# Sort the tags content by mobile & desktop breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I wonder how can I order my divs basing on mobile and desktop breakpoints. I have:

```
<div>
    <span> foo </span>
    <span> bar </span>
    <span> baz </span>
</div>
```

I would like to reach a result in which:

only on mobile breakpoint **firstspan** & **secondspan** are on the same line, so:

```
foobar
baz
```

and only on desktop breakpoint **secondspan** & **thirdspan** are on the same line, so:

```
foo
barbaz
```

I usually use Tailwind (but I think this information is irrelevant), I tried with flex, break-line but nothing, I don't understand how to create this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this using tailwindCSS, you can use [`grid`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns) and make [`col-span`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column) [responsive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design).

In below example, firstspan & secondspan are on first line until small breakpoint, and for screen bigger than small, firstspan is alone on its line and secondspan and thirdspan are on the same line.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="grid grid-cols-2">
  <div class="sm:col-span-2">First span</div>
  <div>Second span</div>
  <div>Third span</div>
</div>
```

---

Edited after comment from @davide

To have the elements on the same line, the easiest solution would be to repeat the **secondspan** twice, and use [`responsive breakpoints`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) with [`display`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display) classes to hide or display it depending on the screen size.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <span>First span</span>
  <span class="sm:hidden">Second span</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="hidden sm:inline">Second span</span> 
  <span>Third span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I intend on the same line like a sentence, with columns layout I'd have separated columns with their spaces between them.

Comment: Ok! The easy way to achieve this would be to repeat the **secondspan** twice, use [`responsive breakpoints`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) with [`display`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display) classes. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok ! Thank you I reached the result with your help! Your code works but at the second <div> I had to add a class="sm:flex" to display on the same line the span. So if you can I suggest you to update the snippet for help future people.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I don't understand your comment though, as the code I sent seem to work as expected. In this case, adding `sm:flex` to the second `div` would only be relevant it the child elements were `div`, but there are `span`